# Trying to pass SSH password for BitBucket repo through Swift

Tags: swift, git, macos, ssh

I am trying to build a MacOS app in Swift that would automate the viewing of an HTML file that has been pushed into the stage version of a documentation site. It's a pretty large doc site (10,000+ files) and the process, though not overly convoluted can be a pain sometimes. Since most of the tech writer work in a silo of sorts, each specializing in an area of our product line I thought it would be convenient to have a little app sitting on their desktop where they could create a library of files they work on, select one, and view it's HTML output in a browser. The first step in this process is to pull the repo.

I've built desktop apps that run a shell to call git commands before with no problems. And this one is functioning as expected, except the as expected is I need to authenticate into an SSH key in order to have the command be successful. I am not sure how to or if that is even possible through swift.

Here is what I have so far. The first function (in ViewController) is called from a button action, it sets up the paths needed and the git command.

```
@IBAction func pullRepo(_ sender: Any) {
    
    myTask = Task()
    myTask?.taskType = .previewFile
    myTask?.subTaskType = .pullRepo
    
    //set up path to repo
    let strComponizeRepo = "file:///Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/xxxxxx/Docs/Repos/app_console-docs"
    let repoURL = URL(string: strComponizeRepo)
    
    //set up git terminal path
    if let repoURL = repoURL {
        
        let strTerminalPath = myAppManager.makePath(repoURL)
            
        //set up command
        let gitRoot = "git --git-dir \(strTerminalPath).git --work-tree \(strTerminalPath) fetch origin/master | git --git-dir \(strTerminalPath).git --work-tree \(strTerminalPath)"
        let strGitCommand = gitRoot + " pull"
        
        myAppManager.runGitShell("/bin/bash", repoURL.absoluteString, strGitCommand, completion: {(strResults:String) in
            print(strResults)
        })
        
    } else {
        print("There was an error setting up the repo URL")
    }
}
```

There are two calls to a class named AppManager. The first, takes a file path and converts it to a Terminal friendly one. In this example I am hard coding the path but in my other apps users could select different repos through the FileManager and so I needed to convert them. Just left that process in place in case this project expands.

```
func makePath(_ fileURL:URL) -> String {
    var strASPath = "~/"
    
    if let indexOfDesktop = fileURL.pathComponents.firstIndex(of: "Desktop") {
        
        for (idx, pathComponent) in fileURL.pathComponents.enumerated(){
            if idx >= indexOfDesktop {
                strASPath = strASPath + pathComponent + "/"
            }
        }
    } else {
        //TODO: Display an error message
    }
    
    return strASPath
}
```

and the function to run the shell

```
func runGitShell(_ launchPath:String, _ repoPath:String, _ command: String, completion: stringClosure) {
    
    //set up the task, we are going to pass the path to the git repo
    //the command is the function we want to run in the script
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = launchPath//"/bin/bash"
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

    completion(output)
}
```

My guess is I can pass the ssh user/pass in the arguments. I'm assuming this based on [this page](https://srvfail.com/how-to-provide-ssh-password-inside-a-script-or-oneliner/). However, my attempt failed:

I changed the arguments to this but got a directory not found error (below are my log results in xcode):

> `/bin/bash: expect -c 'spawn ssh xxxxx.xxxxxx@xxxxx.com "git --git-dir ~/Desktop/xxxxxx/Docs/Repos/app_console-docs/.git --work-tree ~/Desktop/xxxxxx/Docs/Repos/app_console-docs/ fetch origin/master | git --git-dir ~/Desktop/xxxxxx/Docs/Repos/app_console-docs/.git --work-tree ~/Desktop/xxxxxxx/Docs/Repos/app_console-docs/ pull"; expect "password:"; send "xxxxxxxxx)"; interact': No such file or directory`

Any ideas how to accomplish this would be appreciated as well as any code improvement suggestions.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to use `|` with `Process`, you have to do it yourself with a `Pipe()` (see `standardInput`). Si the first lines shouldn't work. That's one issue, might be not related to your issue, but I think you might need to fix this first.

Comment: @Larme Alternatively, you can spawn a shell, and use it to parse the rest of your commands, including pipes and file redirections